# Database Connection Failed

Tags: php, mysql

While I am browsing my online app in the server I got an error like

> Database Connection Failed
>
> User coule_com@c17564 already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections.

But this is working well in my local system. And this error occurs ANY TIME when I navigate in the server. If i refresh the browser i can able to move further. But I in need to solve this issue.

will anybody help me to solve this issue ?

connection code :

```
function makeConnection() { 
    global $config;
    $this->ConLink = mysql_pconnect($config['DBHostName'],$config['DBUserName'],$config['DBPassword']) or die("Database Connection Failed". mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($config['DBName'], $this->ConLink);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your connection code? Maybe you're (mis)using persistent connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to contact your host and get them to up the connection limit. if they won't, you need to find a better host. this is simply a fact of life in web-based applications.

Answer (score 3):

Are you closing the connections when you're done with them?

If not, then I would assume there's lots of database connection objects lying around just waiting for GC to pick them up, and until it does, you risk running out of available connections.

Comment: The application is a shopping-cart site. In this how can i able to close the connection. I think that i the connection availability all the time. This is an assumption. Any suggestions will be acceptable
Thanks

Comment: Well, the "php" tag and the mention of a browser suggests that he... is trying to run a web application written in PHP, which means that all the connection objects are collected in the end of request (which shouldn't take long) automatically. Unless, of course, he has explicitly specified that the connection has to be persistent.